# Is it wrong to link /dev/random to /dev/urandom on Linux?

Tags: linux, security, random

I'm currently testing `gpg --genkey` on a Linux VM. Unfortunately, this software seems to rely on `/dev/random` to gather entropy and politely asks the user to manually type screens after screens of cryptographically random input so it may eventually end-up with generating a key, and I've found no command-line parameter to tell it to use another file as entropy source (the guy [on this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZSa-d_9O5DA&feature=youtu.be&t=719) encounters the very same issue...).

However, the user should be free to choose to use `/dev/urandom` instead since [there is nothing wrong with it](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/3939/32746). It is there mainly as a reminiscence of older PRNG algorithms which were weaker from a cryptographic point of view. For instance, while [NetBSD manpage](http://netbsd.gw.com/cgi-bin/man-cgi?rnd%20%20NetBSD-current) grants that the distinction may still be useful at very early booting stage, it describes such distinction as *"folklore"* and an *"imaginary theory that defends only against fantasy threat models"*. Not anybody agrees with either [the amount of entropy required by this command](http://www.philandstuff.com/2013/03/14/why-does-gpg-need-so-much-entropy.html) nor the fact that entropy is something which is actually actually consumed as stated in [GPG manpage](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manpage.en.html) (*"PLEASE, don't use this command unless you know what you are doing, it may remove precious entropy from the system!"*).

I've read about [people installing the `rngd` daemon](https://serverfault.com/q/303935/228297) and configure it to use `/dev/urandom` as entropy source to feed `/dev/random`, but I find such practice heavily dirty.

I tried to workaround the problem in the FreeBSD way by removing `/dev/random` and linking it to `/dev/urandom` instead:

```
rm /dev/random
ln -s /dev/urandom /dev/random
```

I see this as a setting telling *"I trust `/dev/urandom` as entropy source"*.

I feared I would encounter some error of some kind, but this seems to provide the expected result since the command now returns successfully immediately.

My question is: **is there any known, practical and wrong side-effect of linking `/dev/random` to `/dev/urandom` on Linux systems as done by default on FreeBSD systems?** Or could one envisage to set this permanently (in a script at the end of the boot process for instance) in case of repetitive issues due to `/dev/random` locking some service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Myths about urandom](http://www.2uo.de/myths-about-urandom/), there is no known attack on /dev/urandom that would not also be an attack on /dev/random. The main problem that a Linux system has is when it cloned and run as several VMs without resetting the saved entropy pool after the cloning. That is a corner case that tangential to what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Well one thing different about `/dev/random` is that it stops output after the entropy pool is used. try this:

```
$ cat /dev/random
(a few short lines of gibberish)^C
$
```

`/dev/urandom` however will reuse the same pool to continue output. as shown here:

```
$ cat /dev/urandom
(tons of gibberish fills the screen)^C
$
```

(When you try to cat these special devices, your prompt might be messed up. Just type `reset` and enter, your terminal will be back to normal)

Use `/dev/urandom` when you just need to fill up something with a constant flow of "randomish" bits. Use `/dev/random` for keys that you need to be absolutely random.

Comment: The question of the OP was: _is there any known, practical and wrong side-effect of linking /dev/random to /dev/urandom on Linux systems as done by default on FreeBSD systems?_

Comment: Interesting, if the difference is this pronounced then they should not be linked.  Most other discussions eventually reach consensus of no difference after boot up but this behaviour might indicate a longer lasting difference.

Answer (score -3):

In Linux, `/dev/random` gives high quality random bits. They are derived from sources that are *not* predictable and *not* repeatable, external to the machine. In contrast, `/dev/urandom` uses the same random data as `/dev/random` (if available), if there is none, it uses a pseudo-random number generator, which is *deterministic*. For most purposes, it is unpredictable enough, but *not* for very demanding applications like cryptography, and much less for creating long-lived keys like for GPG.

Comment: This is wrong. [`/dev/urandom` is fine for cryptography](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3936/is-a-rand-from-dev-urandom-secure-for-a-login-key/3939#3939).

Comment: @Gilles that depends on your degree of paranoia. For GPG, *everybody* is affected by your key (indirectly).

Comment: If you don't trust `/dev/urandom`, you have no reason to trust GPG either.

Comment: @Gilles they are different algorithms and code bases.

Comment: @vonbrand: Depending on my degree of paranoia, if I have to choose between a mathematically checked PRNG to generate randomness or a user forced to type a full screen of garbage "asdfghasdfghasdfgh", I would by far choose the software PRNG. I understand your point that a computer is not good at generating randomness, but humans are even worse at it. Nevertheless, to come back to my question, except from the `urandom` vs. `random` debate, do you confirm that replacing the `/dev/random` file by a link should have no other side-effect and be a viable alternative to the `rngd` trick I mentionned?

Comment: Note that man 4 urandom states (at least for Kernel 3.16.0)

<block> If there is not sufficient entropy in the entropy pool, the returned values are <i>theoretically  vulnerable to a crypto‐graphic  attack on the algorithms used by the driver</i>. Knowledge of how to do this is not available in the current unclassified literature, but it is theoretically possible that such an attack may exist.
</block>
and goes on to say
<block><i> As a general rule, /dev/urandom should be used for everything except long-lived GPG/SSL/SSH keys.</i></block>

Comment: This is wrong. They use the SAME RNG, but random blocks if it guesses that there's not enough entropy.